# Outlook JS Add-In + Outlook REST API

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, office-js, outlook-restapi

I want my Outlook 365 integration to use both, the Outlook JS Add-In API, and the Outlook REST API.

But as I see it, it has separate permission/credential handling:

- The Outlook Add-In API has following permissions: Restricted, ReadItem, ReadWriteItem, or ReadWriteMailbox
- The Outlook REST API has full OAuth2 support with scopes, e.g. the `offline_access` scope which interest me the most.

What I wan't is to use the Outlook Add-In to give the user additional UI elements, and use the Outlook REST API to keep my data in sync with Outlook data.

Is it possible without forcing the user to give consent twice? That is firstly by giving consent for the Add-In when installing it, and then consent for our app which uses the Outlook REST API for sync jobs.

Comment: Here you can find the answer:
[Use the Outlook REST APIs from an Outlook add-in](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/master/docs/outlook/use-rest-api.md)

Comment: Looks like I can't use this functionality since I need a refresh token to do stuff on behalf of the user when he isn't using the add-in (to handle push notifications). This approach gives me just an access token with a limited life time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge, it is not possible now without asking the end user to complete a second, OAUTH based, authentication flow.

Note that you can use EWS (Exchange Web Services, which is not REST) without a secondary authentication flow, if you need to access data not provided by Office.js

Have a look at `getUserIdentityTokenAsync` or `makeEwsRequestAsync` [here](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/outlook/Office.context.mailbox).

Comment: Thanks, I know about the EWS methods in the office.js API, however what I need is the possibility to access the users calendar when he is not using the add-in, doing some sync work. So looks like a second OAuth to keep the refresh/access token is the way to go.

Comment: Yup, it made me sure that I have to make a second authentication flow, the EWS calls from the Outlook Add-In are too limited for my needs. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a second Auth flow, you can use Office.context.mailbox.getCallbackTokenAsync({ isRest: true }, function (result) ... to get the access token, then you can consume the Calendar REST API using JQuery/Ajax for instance.

Comment: Format your question to make it more legible.

Comment: but can I then store the token in the back-end and use it from there? Will I get also an refresh token if the access token gets expired? Can I make all the calls from the REST API, e.g. subscribe to push notifications?

Answer (score 0):

you can use Office.js and you can get token from it and token is used for performing ajax call. I am giving example here

```
var _mailbox = Office.context.mailbox;
_mailbox.getCallbackTokenAsync({ isRest: true }, function (result) {
    if (result.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
       var  accessToken = result.value;

         var userDetail;
     var url = Office.context.mailbox.restUrl+ "/v2.0/me";
   try {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url,
        contentType: "application/json",
        headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken },
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            userDetail = data;
        },
        error: function (textStatus, errorThrown) {

            userDetail = null;//doesnt goes here
        }

    });
}
catch (error)
{
    userDetail = null;
    writeLog(error);
}
  }
  }
```

Above code give current user detail including first Name , email adddress and many more, You can perform several other operation such create folder, move email ,delete email and many more

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain the Outlook REST API's access token from in your outlook JS Plug-in using the
 `Office.context.mailbox.getCallbackTokenAsync` method as show below

```js
Office.context.mailbox.getCallbackTokenAsync({isRest: true}, function(result){
  if (result.status === "succeeded") {
    var accessToken = result.value;

    // Use the access token.
    getCurrentItem(accessToken);
  } else {
    // Handle the error.
  }
});
```

Source: [Get an access token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/use-rest-api#get-an-access-token)